# What does まんが in this passage mean?

Tags: definitions, compounds

> まんが日本昔話みたいな婆ちゃんの声に、説得力があった。

Is it manga as in 漫画? If so why is it not 日本昔話まんが but まんが日本昔話?

Comment: https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%98%94%E3%81%B0%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97 Specifically, the 声 refers to that of 市原悦子.

Answer (score 3):

As @naruto cited in his comment, it is [a title of an anime series](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%98%94%E3%81%B0%E3%81%AA%E3%81%97) (not *manga* medium-wise, though).

> If so why is it not 日本昔話まんが but まんが日本昔話?

日本昔話まんが would sound like "a Japanese fairy tale comic", and it is a valid phrasing as such. But here, the name まんが日本昔話 is almost surely read in two parts as まんが・日本昔話, and similar to what you might say in Engilsh *Japanese Fairy Tales: The Comic* (of course, again, it's actually an anime).

This type of naming is quite popular for educational/documentary materials, as we also have [まんが日本の歴史](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E6%AD%B4%E5%8F%B2), [マンガ日本経済入門](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AC%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E7%B5%8C%E6%B8%88%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80) (manga & anime), [まんがどうして物語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E7%89%A9%E8%AA%9E) (anime), [まんがサイエンス](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9) and so on.

Comment: We also say 映画ドラえもん ("Doraemon: The Movie"), 小説ドラゴンクエスト ("Dragon Quest: The Novel"), etc.